# Rspec | Missing id for create controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am getting Id missing nil error in my create controller spec. Yet I have passed ID stuff in it still facing same everytime. Here my create spec and controller file

**Create Spec**

```
  describe 'POST :create' do
    context 'with valid data' do
      let(:valid_data) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:student) }
      it 'redirect to show page' do
        post :create, student: valid_data
        expect(response).to redirect_to(student_path(assigns[:student]))
      end
    end
  end
```

**Student Controller**

```
  def create
    @student = current_user.students.build(student_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
        format.html { redirect_to @student }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private

  def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(:Student_Prefix, :First_Name, :Middle_Name, :Last_Name, :Father_Prefix, :Father_Name, :Father_Middle_Name, :Father_Last_Name, :Mother_Prefix, :Mother_Name, :Mother_Middle_Name, :Mother_Last_Name,  :user_id)
  end
```

**Error**

```
1) StudentsController POST :create with valid data redirect to show page
   Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(student_path(assigns[:student]))

   ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
     No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"students", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
   # ./spec/controllers/students_controller_spec.rb:38:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `save` is failing in `StudentsController`, so `@student` doesn't have an ID. You're getting the error when you try to build the path in your spec:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(student_path(assigns[:student]))
```

`assigns[:student]` doesn't have an ID.

Comment: I tried passing ID in controller but getting same error everytime, even I tried changing redirect path to root_path but with getting this error `Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>`

Comment: Your controller is not issuing a redirect because `@student.save` is failing and returning false. Try looking at the errors in your test file: `puts assigns[:student].errors`. This should give you an idea why `save` is failing

Comment: thanks for help, solution you provide works for me. Instead of simple `errors` method I used `errors.full_messages` which prints full error message.